# Loquunturne homines in Roma hodie parum Latine?

Tags: contemporary-latin

Ibo in Romam hac aestate. Loquunturne plurimi homines in ea urbe parum Latine? Comprehendantne me si rogabo eos res ut "Ubi est latrina?" in lingua Latina? Aut discenda est mihi lingua Italica hodierna quia ero in Roma?

Comment: Romae (locativo casu utimur) si eris, quaere modice, quaeso, et invenies. Deinde, si tibi placet, nos certiores facies respondendo hic (vel potius, mea sentetnia, in Meta). Sed nobis cavendum est ne temere credituri simus quiquid sensibus nostris patet et pro veritate tota statim habeamus. nam si et hiemaveris illic fortasse alia experieris.

Comment: @d_e Et, dum Romae sum, possumne uti lingua Latina? Aut discenda est mihi lingua Italica hodierna?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been in Rome a couple of times,  and the situation is pretty clear:
essentially nobody understands a word in Latin.
English will serve you much better, and a bit of Italian will also help.
Latin is useful for reading ancient inscriptions but not really anything else.

Rome does have some people who understand Latin, but it's not very helpful for the purpose of speaking Latin on the streets:

- They are a small minority.
- Many are only proficient in written Latin.
- Local pronunciations vary so wildly that the person you are talking to might not realise you are trying to speak Latin even if they speak it. (I've seen this happen many times with other languages.)

So yes, if you want to brush up a language before going to Rome, do Italian instead of Latin.